# css3 animation not working properly on first page request sometimes, but afterwards

Tags: jquery, css, animation, caching, pageload

I think it might be a cache problem, on very first page request on my [site](http://dev-ankur.github.io/portfolio), the '*flipInX*' animation using **animate.css** is not working sometimes, but works properly after loading on every subsequent page request. Now try reloading the page while removing cache(shift + F5), and the problem occurs, sometimes. The animation other than that first animation('*zoomIn*' animation) seems to work everytime. Its only the first animation which is causing problem. Its like as soon as the text becomes visible its animation is already over or about to over(visible only little animation that's left). I have added the code in jquery as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#particles-js .pro-title").css('visibility', 'visible').addClass("animated flipInX");

    var events = "webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend";

    $("#particles-js .pro-title").one(events, function(){

        $("#particles-js .pro-desc").css('visibility', 'visible').addClass("animated zoomIn");
    });

    .....
}
```

So I think it should come visible and then animating after loading, but its not happening at very first page load. What should I do to make it visible and properly animating at very first page load? As you know, first impression is the last impression, so I need to make it proper! Please HELP!

Comment: It sounds like you have some sort of race condition. Good that you're using `$(document).ready()`, but are the elements you're trying to animate present in the html markup, or are they possibly being added dynamically by another javascript function? If the latter, the function in question may be trying to animate them before they are added to the DOM, which will not work.

Comment: @nvioli : The elements are there already and I am trying to add the animation class dynamically under `$(document).ready()`....I think it should work then!??